# MFC edit control update

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I try to update an edit control's text, using it's added variable, which is a `CString` but i'm failing it.

```
m_sNrAuto = "some text";  
UpdateData(TRUE);
```

I also tried using `UpdateWindow()`, but the edit control remains blank. I know i can do it by using `SetWindowText()`, but i also saw some snippets where `SetWindowText()` it's not used, the update is done by passing a value to an affiliated CString.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `UpdateData(false);`

- `true` means Control=>Data
- `false` means Data=>Control

Sometimes you have to do

```
UpdateData(true);  // snapshot ALL controls data
m_sNrAuto = "some text";  // tweak the one you actually need updated
UpdateData(false);  // this pushes ALL data, not just the one you tweaked
```

Comment: For the record, the parameter is called `SaveAndValidate` which means save to a variable if `true`.

Comment: perhaps you also need `UpdateWindow();` after the UpdateData(false) - this will force it to refresh dialog with new values

Comment: Its that UpdateWindow function that finally got me over the hump.  I was updating an edit control during a button push's length processing, and that wouldn't show up until the button processing finished.  Doing the UpdateWindow finally got the status to show.