# Need to call twice a setter to force GUI refresh in MFC

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I'm using a MFC ComboBox control to change some parameter which has constituencies on the IP range available ( only/ no broadcast IP for example).

I need to call the range modification function twice to force the refreshing on the showed values : why ?

### Behaviour :

[image]

```
                         One call to range modification
```

[image: two call to range modification]

```
                         Two calls to range modification
```

### Source code :

```
void CIPAddressBugDlg::OnChangeCombo()
{

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    ChangeIPRange();
    //ChangeIPRange();

}


void CIPAddressBugDlg::ChangeIPRange()
{
    BYTE nField0, nField1, nField2, nField3;

    if ( Combo.GetCurSel() )
    {
        IpAddress.GetAddress(nField0, nField1, nField2, nField3);
        if ( nField0  < (BYTE) 224 )
            nField0 = 224;
        IpAddress.SetAddress(nField0, nField1, nField2, nField3);
        IpAddress.SetFieldRange(0, 224 , 232 );
    }
    else
    {
        IpAddress.GetAddress(nField0, nField1, nField2, nField3);
        if ( nField0  >= (BYTE) 224 )
            nField0 = 223;
        IpAddress.SetAddress(nField0, nField1, nField2, nField3);
        IpAddress.SetFieldRange(0, 0 , 223 );
    }
}
```

Combo is a ComboBox control and IpAddress a CIPAddressCtrl. I'm compiling on VS C++ 6.0 (yes I know -_- ) running Windows XP.

( I can also upload the whole toy project if necessary )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `SetFieldRange` before `SetAddress` else Windows will ignore the `SetAddress` because it's out of range.

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason why it didn't work in the first place !

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the value in the edit field until the call to UpdateData is performed the second time.  I'm not sure why you are relying on UpdateData within OnChangeCombo, but, that's  what is causing the field to update.  Try removing the call to UpdateData, and adding a call to SetWindowText, or, a dialog command equivalent within ChangeIPRange () to update the IP data field.

Comment: The UpdateData is useless here ( it was just an attempt to see if it could help). Anyway, being a non-blocking quirk, I will leave the double call as is, but it would be nice to have an explanation why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably as simple as this:

```
void CIPAddressBugDlg::OnChangeCombo()
{

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    ChangeIPRange();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

The changes made in `ChangeIPRange` only get updated to the control when you call `UpdateData(FALSE)`.

Comment: Nope. I tried this answer, but to no avail : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111894/mfc-edit-control-update